Proper way to transfer data to a composite form
I'm searching for a good way to transfer data to my form.
I'm working on an app that can help with maintaining detail manufacturing. Each detail can have some subdetails, each subdetail is a detail itself so it can have some more subdetails and so on.
Here you can see how such hierarchy can look like:

Detail itself has a lot of fields - only a part of them can be used in a form, and some of the fields (as detailId, parentId or subDetailIds) are crucial for proper logic. I've grouped fields into parts for a better understanding:
class Detail {

  // ---- Can be changed ----
  String orderNumber;
  String name;
  String? mainInformation;
  String? drawingImagePath;
  DateTime? drawingExpirationDate;
  String? regularImagePath;


  // --- Important for logic (displaying delete buttons, managing detail-detail relations ---
  int? id;
  List<int> subDetailIds;
  int? parentId;


  // --- Cannot be changed from form view ---
  String? comment;
  String? techProcess;
  DetailType type;
  DetailStatus status;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime modifiedAt;
}  

I am using the same form for adding and editing my detail. Some important info:

You can add new subdetails  - they will be saved to a database if you submit that form. Deleting newly added subdetail should just remove editable fields as that detail is not yet added to a database;
When editing a detail, you can see the detail itself and its subdetails - one level deep, not all the subdetails of all the subdetails. If you delete a subdetail, you also delete all of its subdetails down the tree;
List of subdetails can be expanded or hidden.


Filled form:

I am trying to find the best way to pass such data and operate it on the form view.
Each detail and subdetail has its own name, info and other fields, so initially I've stored all the data of every detail in controllers, even if there were no editable field for such a controller:
final List<TextEditingController> _nameControllers = [];
final List<TextEditingController> _mainInfoControllers = [];
final List<TextEditingController> _commentControllers = [];
...

This approach seems bad for me as storing some data into a controller that is used only to preserve data when submitting is strange. So I switched to the object approach, where I pass a whole detail to the form and, based on that, display information without using controllers. For example, loading subDetails looks like that:
Future<void> _loadSubDetails(List<int> subDetailIds) async {
    final subDetails = await Future.wait(
      subDetailIds.map((id) => dbManager.readDetail(id)),
    );

    final detailDTOs = subDetails.map((detail) {
      return DetailDTO(
        id: detail!.id,
        parentId: detail.parentId,
        orderNumber: detail.orderNumber,
        name: detail.name,
        mainInformation: detail.mainInformation,
        comment: detail.comment,
        techProcess: detail.techProcess,
        type: detail.type,
        status: detail.status,
        drawingExpirationDate: detail.drawingExpirationDate,
        drawingImagePath: detail.drawingImagePath,
        regularImagePath: detail.regularImagePath,
      );
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      _detailDTO.subDetails = detailDTOs;
    });
  }

This approach looks a bit better for me, because here I can pass only the data that will be changed. However, I meet some issues. But without controllers, it becomes hard to maintain changes before I submit my form. For example, if we change some field of the subdetail and then hide the expansion tile, that data will be lost as we do not write it anywhere.
So for now, I think that I have to use some combined approaches: controllers for the fields that can be changed and DTO for id, parentId, subDetailIds to build proper relationships. I've created a manager that will operate the controllers:
class DetailFormManager {
  final Map<int, TextEditingController> idToNameControllers = {};
  final Map<int, TextEditingController> idToInfoControllers = {};
  final Map<int, TextEditingController> idToExpirationControllers = {};

  TextEditingController getController(Map<int, TextEditingController> controllers, int detailId, String initialValue) {
    if (!controllers.containsKey(detailId)) {
      controllers[detailId] = TextEditingController(text: initialValue);
    }
    return controllers[detailId]!;
  }

  void dispose() {
    nameControllers.values.forEach((c) => c.dispose());
    infoControllers.values.forEach((c) => c.dispose());
    expirationControllers.values.forEach((c) => c.dispose());
  }
}

But for newly added details, I have no ID yet, so I should create some temporary id for it, which seems bad for me.
Long story short, I would like to know whether there is a good way to pass data to my form with such logic. I would highly appreciate any help or info/links where I can read more about this. If something is not clear - please, don't hesitate to ask, I can provide more code and information about my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

'''But without controllers, it becomes hard to maintain changes before I submit my form.
For example, if we change some field of the subdetail and then hide the expansion tile, that data will be lost as we do not write it anywhere.''' - tried to use keys? see 10 minute video When to Use Keys - Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 4

Hi! What is the question? Sounds like a state management problem to me. Can you simplify a little.

@MaLa I agree, it can sound more like state management problem. To simplify, I would like to know what way of managing form state will be better here - using controllers, some DTO or combining these two approaches?

@pskink Thanks a lot for suggestion, with keys I can eliminate the problem with state management. Will try to use it

Have you tried to implement a JSON data format? The purpose of it is that a key could have multiple values nested on it.
